# AWS IotCore with Amplify not receiving topic messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-iot-core

I'm trying to create a live chat using iotCore and amplify in Next.js.
I just follow a tons of guides about how to set amplify and how to use Iot but nothing.
I created a cognito user pool
Created a identityPoolId with the correct policies, i even created iot policy with all access and setup next with amplify.
[That's my next.js app] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RQVc.png)

[That's the network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yChpR.png)

But nothing appear in console when i try to send a test mqtt client message.

I tried to create an Object on IotCore console but still not working